# What are the best ways to avoid Out of memory issues in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I am working on one application which has lots of screens, custom views and API calls on almost each screen. Sometimes when the user uses the app for a long time, it gets crashed because of `Out of Memory` issues. 
Ideally, I followed all guidelines while developing app and ARC takes care of memory usage. So what are the best way to avoid such memory issues?

Comment: I have seen so many big apps which work very efficiently. you can't let ARC to protect your app from crashing. If your app is crashing due to memory usage you had an issue with your code. Provide the details about the crash and add some code.

Comment: FYI ARC doesn't take care of memory usage.

Comment: Ok fine, I will get the crash report and provide soon.

Answer (score -1):

Code has a built-in memory profiler that can help you with this issue - for a tutorial on how to use it, this might be helpful http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Otherwise, if dealloc isn't being called it could be a symptom of a retain cycle (two objects maintain strong references to each other, so they are never deallocated).

Comment: ... and this is an issue that might be assisted by the notion of "weak references."  While this concept is normally presented in the context of creating self-referencing data structures that CAN be cleaned up, it is also useful when you wish to create references to things that (you say ...) can be disposed-of, if memory begins to get tight.  (If the object in question is harvested, your pointer to it will be set to "nil," and you must therefore test for this.  Very-unpredictable race conditions can occur.)

Comment: ... still, I would echo the opinion that, "this is probably a design issue."  If the application "has a lot of screens," it might well not(!) have the luxury of keeping all of those data-structures, for all those screens, "alive" at the same time.  Instead of relying too-much on the behavior of the memory manager, "with all the race-conditions and debug-ugliness thereunto appertaining," you might well need to address this, as a design(!) issue, yourself.  Data structures might well need to be explicitly disposed-of, and then re-created. In the mobile world, you must be STINGY(!) with RAM!